# How to patch in a for loop

Tags: matlab, for-loop

i want to patch points to obtain a square and do it for all other points on the axis, but i want to do it in a for loop.. Thereafter, i would apply some transformation properties to the patched points. This is what i have done so far. Any help will be well appreciated.

```
whitebg('g')
 axis on
% first patch point on the axis
pts2 = [0 0 1 1 0;0 1 1 0 0];
% last patch point on the axis
pts3 = [29 29 30 30 29;29 30 30 29 29];
[n m] = size(pts2);
[o p] = size(pts3);
axis([0 30 0 30])
shg
theta=0;
dx=0;
dy=0;
 d=patch(pts1(1,1:end),pts1(2,1:end),'b*-');
   for pts1 = pts2:pts3
       if  (d==patch(pts1(1,1:end),pts1(2,1:end),'b*-'))
           delete(d)
       end
       %function to process
       rot = [cosd(theta) sind(theta);-sind(theta) cosd(theta)];
       trans = [1 0 dx;0 1 dy; 0 0 1];
       homogeneous_rot = eye(3);
       homogeneous_rot(1:2,1:2) = rot;
       homogeneous_pts1 = [pts1; ones(1,5)];
       trans_pts1 = trans*homogeneous_rot*homogeneous_pts1;
       hold off
       f=patch(trans_pts1(1,1:end),trans_pts1(2,1:end),'r*-');
       draw now
   end
```

Comment: Hi. You need to explain better what you are triying to do and why it does not work.

Comment: If I run the code, I get this error `Error in ... (line14); Undefined function or variable 'pts1'.`

Comment: @ Ander, thanks. Actually, i'm trying to use patch to place square-shaped  tile mosaic at different directions. i have actually implemented it and it worked, but i did it statically. i had to change points for every patch. e.g for 1st patch, i have points [0 0 1 1 0;0 1 1 0 0], 2nd patch i have points [0 0 1 1 0;2 3 3 2 2]; till i patch the entire axis. Note that these points form a square. Then, for "theta" i will retrieve it from a 2 dimensional array later, so i just made it 0 to make it easy to understand.

Comment: @Jorgen, thanks. i get that error too. please is there a better way of implementing the for loop?

Comment: Try to explain more what you are trying. It is not clear to me how you use the `patch` command, can you give an example.

Comment: @Jorgen, the patch points are the coordinates of the vertices of the square i want to patch. The patch command draws a colored square at the specified points.e.g point 1 is [0 0 1 1 0;0 1 1 0 0], point 2 is [0 0 1 1 0;2 3 3 2 2], point 3 is [0 0 1 1 0;4 5 5 4 4]. i have as many as 225 points on the axis that i want to patch, but i dont want to do it one after the other because the code will be very long, so i want to do it in a loop.

Comment: How do you determine the next point, it seems to jump irregular (from point 1 to point 2)

Comment: The size of a tile(x by y) is 1unit by 1unit .So i place the tile in a 2 by 2 block to allow for enough space for rotation of the square. e.g first block has point [0 0 2 2 0;0 2 2 0 0.].So i patch the tile of point [0 0 1 1 0;0 1 1 0 0] within this block.The next 2 by 2 block as i move up the column has point [0 0 2 2 0;2 4 4 2 2]. Likewise i patch the tile of point [0 0 1 1 0;2 3 3 2 2] within this block .The next 2 by 2 block  as i move up the column has point [0 0 2 2 0;4 6 6 4 4]. So i patch the tile of point [0 0 1 1 0;4 5 5 4 4] within this block. So i continue this for the entire axis.

Comment: @Jorgen, was the example i gave useful?

Comment: Somewhat, but at the moment I don't have too much time. Sorry

Comment: Let my try to understand. You want squares of 2x2, One question though. Why do you use 5 points to describe the patch, isn't 4 enough: `px = [0 0 2 2]; py = [0 2 2 0]`? Second, do you want patches of both the blocks and tiles or just the tile?. And what do you want to rotate, the tile or the block? Does the tile rotate around the center point of the block.

Comment: 2x2 is for the block.i want 1x1 tile.The 5points to describe the patch,see it like drawing a square.e.g px=[0 0 1 1 0]; py=[0 1 1 0 0] with start point at (0,0),then move to (0,1) to complete one side of the square, to (1,1) for the 2nd side,to (1,0) for the 3rd side, and to (0,0) for the 4th side. Also,i just want to patch the tile not the block.The tile doesn't rotate around the center point of the block, after rotation the tile translates to another point,so i translate it back to where i want it to be. i've taken care of rotation and translation but my issue is actually to patch in a loop.

Comment: Thanks Jorgen for your time.